Struggling with mutate column/case_when "AND OR" statements
I am looking at resistance of urine infections to certain antibiotics.
The antibiotics I am looking at are nitrofurantoin (NIT), trimethoprim (TRI) and cefalexin (CLX).
I wanted to create two new columns.
Column 1:
Where there is resistance to at least 2 antibiotics
Column 2:
Where there is resistance to at least 3 antibiotics.
In the picture you should be able to see what I want it to look like.
My initial attempt at trying to do the three resistant antibiotics was as follows
Urine1 %>% 
  mutate(Threereesistant = case_when(
    str_detect(CLX, "Resistant") & str_detect(NIT, "Resistant") & str_detect(TRI, "Resistant") ~ three resistant),
    TRUE~"NA")

But it doesnt work and it wouldnt account for the multiple OR statements necessary for the 2 resistance column to work.


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images

Try the following code:
library(dplyr)

Urine1 = Urine1 %>% 
  mutate(cnt = rowSums(.[, c("CLX", "NIT", "TRI")] == "Resistant"), 
         resistance_to_2 = ifelse(cnt>=2, "Yes", "No"),
         resistance_to_3 = ifelse(cnt>=3, "Yes", "No")) %>%
  select(-cnt)

Logic: the variable cnt contains a rowwise count of the number of number of Resistant. It is then used create two variables based on the number of Resistant found in each row. And since cnt is just a working variable, it is dropped using the select() function.

use >= rather than == eg the second row. Note that if yes to 3, its automatically yes to 2.

@Onyambu are you able to clarify a little more about what you mean and where exactly you would put it and what difference it would make.

@B. Christian Kamgang are you able to explain a little more about the logic behind your code I cant quite follow what cnt is doing and why you need to select it at the end.
Also I have another problem. Some of the columns have data that is NA. When the results are outputted from the columns that have NA in them the answer is NA in the "resistance_to_2" columns even if the answer should be a yes or a no. Any idea how to fix that. Hugely appreciate your help.

@Onyambu You're right! It's done. Thanks!

@StuartDrazich-Taylor It's done. Let me know if it is clear.
